# Angular ng-repeat iterate over multiple items per iteration

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a dictionary in my controller:

```
thing = {    

    key1 = value1,

    key2 = value2,

    ...

    keyN = valueN,

};
```

I am using ng-repeat to iterate through it like so: `ng-repeat="(key, value) in thing"`

But I want to iterate through multiple values at a time, such that for each iteration, I can use `key1: value1` and `key2: value2`, then the next I can use `key3: value3`, `key4: value4` etc...

Is there a way to iterate through with ng-repeat, iterating more than one item at a time?
Thanks.

Comment: Do you always want to use two consecutive items at a time?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not without changing your model's structure or using additional structure. What I mean by the latter is, you could create an array with key names, like this:

```
$scope.doubled = [['key1', 'key2'], ['key3', 'key4'], ... ];
```

And then the iteration is quite straightforward, e.g.:

```
<div ng-repeat="keys in doubled">
    <div ng-repeat="key in keys">
        {{ thing[key] }}
    </div>
</div>
```

It is also a more reliable way of iterating in a predictible manner, because you should mind that while iterating over the object's properties, **you cannot** (or at least shouldn't) **rely on a specific order of those properties** (see https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/6210).

Comment: Ah thanks for the helpful explanation! The way I am using it in my app would depend on the order of the properties, so I will use a different method.  Thanks for the thorough answer!

Answer (score 0):

I suggest to create a filter:

```
app.filter('coupledItems', function(){
        return function(items){

            var isEven = false;
            var coupledItems = [];
            var temp = {};
            angular.forEach(items, function(item){

                if(isEven){
                    temp['item2'] = item;
                    coupledItems.push(temp);
                    temp = {};
                }
                else{
                    temp['item1'] = item;
                }

                isEven = !isEven;
            });

            if(temp['item1']){ // If odd, put it to last item
                coupledItems.push(temp)
            }

            return coupledItems;
        }
    });
```

When use it:

```
<tr ng-repeat="item in items | coupledItems">
    <td>{{item.item1.key}}</td>
    <td>{{item.item2.key}}</td>
</tr>
```

Comment: For some reason this gives me an infinite digest loop. Any ideas?

Answer (score -1):

Yes.
Example:

```
ng-repeat="t in thing"

{{ t[$index] + t[$index+1] }}
```

Comment: It will still go through all iterations. He wanted to have only half of them.

Comment: I don't believe it works that way. Can you provide a simple example.